# Simultaneously Add Update in smartsheet using C#

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

```
        SmartsheetClient ss = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(accessToken).Build(); 
        Sheet sheet = ss.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        //Add
        Cell[] cellA = new Cell[] { new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[0].Id, "test task1").Build() };
        Row rowA = new Row.AddRowBuilder(null,true, null, null, null).SetCells(cellA).Build();
        ss.SheetResources.RowResources.AddRows(sheetId, new Row[] { rowA });
        Cell[] cellB = new Cell[] { new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[0].Id, "test task2").Build() };
        Row rowB = new Row.AddRowBuilder(null, true, null, null, null).SetCells(cellB).Build();
        ss.SheetResources.RowResources.AddRows(sheetId, new Row[] { rowB });
        Cell[] cellC = new Cell[] { new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[0].Id, "test task3").Build() };
        Row rowC = new Row.AddRowBuilder(null, true, null, null, null).SetCells(cellC).Build();
        ss.SheetResources.RowResources.AddRows(sheetId, new Row[] { rowC });

        //Update
        Cell[] cell = new Cell[] { new Cell.UpdateCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[0].Id, "test task update").Build() };
            Row row = new Row.UpdateRowBuilder(sheet.Rows[2].Id).SetCells(cell).Build();
            ss.SheetResources.RowResources.UpdateRows(sheetId, new Row[] { row });
```

but i get error -
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

on following line-

```
           Row row = new Row.UpdateRowBuilder(sheet.Rows[2].Id).SetCells(cell).Build();
            ss.SheetResources.RowResources.UpdateRows(sheetId, new Row[] { row });
```

because "sheet.Rows.count" is still 0.

hence i added below line -

```
           sheet = ss.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

above following line-

```
           Cell[] cell = new Cell[] { new Cell.UpdateCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[0].Id, "test task update").Build() };
```

and the error goes and my sheet gets updated.

I want to ask if this is the proper way, that one has to call the "GetSheet" again to load the updated sheet and then proceed OR there is some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sheet on the server has changed, so you need another GET to have a local representation that matches.